# how do I write a script to change the discount in the Order Details table

Tags: sql, northwind

In Northwinds how do I write a script to change the discount in the Order Details table on all orders that have an ordered quantity of more than 50 and to show the greatest discount given.

In the northwinds table, do I use MAX or SUM? It's suppose to affect 159 rows. I have this but keep getting an error.

```
SELECT OrderID, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,
MAX (Discount)
FROM [Order Details]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that the database doesnt know how to show you OrderID, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity and still give you a max value of Discount.

When you use aggregate functions, it requires that you group by certain fields.

For example:

```
SELECT OrderID, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity, MAX (Discount)
FROM [Order Details]
group by  OrderID, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity
```

In order to get an order quantity of more than 50 you'd want to use the `HAVING` keyword.

```
SELECT OrderID, ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount
FROM [Order Details]
having Quantity > 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to see wanted to see all of those columns along with the Max Discount then I would suggest using Over partition by, as you can return aggregates without having to group by all of the columns that you are selecting.

```
SELECT OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,
MAX(Discount) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID) as MaxDiscount
from Order Details
```

As for the the quantity over 50 I would just use

```
SELECT OrderID,ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount
FROM Order Details
where Quantity > 50
```